# How do I ensure my Java method never returns null?

Tags: java

I've been reading Uncle Bob's Clean Code and have read many articles on the use of Optionals whenever you are faced with returning a null in a Java method.  I'm currently refactoring my code and I just don't know how to optimize it with Optionals.  Can someone give me some pointers?

```
public UserLog selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);

    return logs.isEmpty() ? null : logs.get(0);
}

private List<UserLog> selectUserLogs(String sql, Object... args) throws DataException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, args);

    return rows.stream().map(this::toUserLogs)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private UserLog toUserLogs(Map<String, Object> row) {
    UserLog userLog = new UserLog("Steven Wozniak", 65, "Male");
    return userLog;
}

/**
* Below shows how selectById is being used in another class
*/
...
public void callingMethod() {
    if(starttime != null && FIVE_HOUR <= durationSinceStartTime() && 
            userLogDao.selectById(userid) != null &&
            userLogDao.selectById(userid).getStartTime() != null) {

        log.warn("Logs came in late");
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble optimizing the `selectById` method.  Since I'm doing a `Collector.toList()` in the `selectUserLogs` method, I can be sure that I will **ALWAYS** get a `List` back.  It could be an empty list, but never a `null`.

My initial attempt was:

```
public Optional<UserLog> selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);
    return Optional.ofNullable(logs.get(0));
    
}
```

However, I completely have no idea how I'm going to optimize the calling of this method and performing the null checks in the `callingMethod()`.  How would I re-write that so that it looks a tad more elegant?

Comment: We are a little different from Stack Overflow, the title of the question should indicate what the code does rather than your concerns about the code. The current title almost makes the question off-topic since we don't answer `How to ...` questions on Code Review. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You do not need `Optional` here. I do this. `List<UserLog> logs = new ArrayList(); logs.addAll(selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid)); return logs;`  This assumes that `selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid)` also returns an empty list if no users are found in the query. If not, you may need to do a similar thing in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you make I/O call as database request, I suggest you to call `selectById` only one time and not 2 time in the if (and maybe a thrid time after).

Then, for the no-null content, it depend of :

1. **If you can create default value**. It doesn't seems to be your case here, but as we don't know your full project, it's possible. You can create temporary value not saved in database which said it's empty like this:

```
public UserLog selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);
    return logs.isEmpty() ? new UserLog(null, 0, "Unknow") : logs.get(0);
}
```

2. If you want that **`selectUserLogs` return a list**, you can do like this for the `selectById` method:

```java
public UserLog selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);
    return logs.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(logs.get(0));
}
```

3. If the `selectUserLogs` is only used here, I suggest you to use the [`Stream#findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method do like this:

```java
private Optional<UserLog> selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);

    return rows.stream().map(this::toUserLogs).findFirst();
}
```

4. A combination of the 2 and 3: 2 methods but using findFirst method:

```java
public UserLog selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);
    return logs.stream().findFirst();
}
```

Here you create a useless stream (which were created before...) but you keep both method. It's fine if the `selectUserLogs` is used somewhere else, and the actual result is what other method are looking for.

Finally, with optional you can do like this in your `callingMethod()` method:

```java
public void callingMethod() {
    if(starttime != null && FIVE_HOUR <= durationSinceStartTime()) {
        userLogDao.selectById(userid).ifPresent(userLog -> {
            if(userLog.getStartTime() != null) {
               log.warn("Logs came in late");
            }
        })
    }
}
```